# Getting error Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime Exception

Tags: c#

I writted code for automatical changer of shifts. Night shift, morning shift, etc. Everything works fine. Current problem with this is when is new month. 5 Month has 31 days. This month have 30 days.
My current code is this:

```
        DateTime lastTime = _lastDateOfLoading;
                DateTime tempTime = Convert.ToDateTime(hourOfLoading);
                DateTime targetTime = new DateTime(DateOfLoading.Year, DateOfLoading.Month, DateOfLoading.Day, tempTime.Hour, tempTime.Minute, tempTime.Second);
                DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

                bool tt1 = false;
                bool tt2 = false;
                bool lt1 = false;
                bool lt2 = false;

                DateTime lt1Min = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, lastTime.Day, 22, 00, 00);
                DateTime lt1Max = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, lastTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
                DateTime lt2Min = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, lastTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
                DateTime lt2Max = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, lastTime.Day, 06, 00, 00);
                DateTime tt1Min = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, targetTime.Day, 22, 00, 00);
                DateTime tt1Max = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, targetTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
                DateTime tt2Min = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, targetTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
                DateTime tt2Max = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, targetTime.Day, 06, 00, 00);

    if ((lastTime >= lt1Min
                       && (lastTime < lt1Max)))
                {
                    lt1 = true;
    }
etc ..
```

It end on lt1Min = new DateTime ...
I think it happen because is june. And lastTime is 22.5.
Any advice how to solve this thing? Nothing helped on current threads here on stackoverlow.
Thank you.

Comment: You can check number of days in the month before create datetime using this code `int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);`

Comment: You can go to the first day of the next month and then subtract 1 day to get last day of month.

Comment: Yes, using count of days solved my problem :) Thanks for advice.